# Is there a reward for building a colony on a more dangerous planet?

Tags: starbound

I am currently considering where to start building my first colony. Building on a less dangerous planet would certainly be less stressful. But is it as rewarding? Is there any incentive for having a colony on a more dangerous planet?

Answer (score 2):

According to [starbounder wiki](http://starbounder.org/Tenant):
Tenants pay various types of rent to the player after a certain time period. Tenants on higher level planets pay more pixels for rent.

```
Tier    Threat          40%     25%     20%     10%     5%
------------------------------------------------------------
1       Harmless        100     150     200     250     300
2       Mostly Harmless 150     200     250     300     350
3       Moderate        200     250     300     350     400
4       Risky           250     300     350     400     450
5       Dangerous       300     350     400     450     500
6       Extreme         350     400     450     500     550
```

Comment: This table doesn't seem to be accurate anymore. I got a tenant on a "Risky" planet (ocean) and she just gave me just 150 pixels.